# A complex soap call using PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap

I've worked on this for about 4 hours and I am real close but just missing the mark – here is what xml needs to look like

```
<ws:Answer QuestionID="Q_CAM_ID" ws:Datatype="string">
        <ws:Value>6838</ws:Value>
</ws:Answer>
```

Here is what I get

```
<ns1:Answer QuestionID="Q_CAM_ID">
    <ns1:Value>6838</ns1:Value>
</ns1:Answer>
```

Using

```
$A1 = new StdClass();          
$A1->QuestionID = 'Q_CAM_ID';  
$A1->Value =6838;
```

No matter what I try I can’t get “ws:Datatype="string"” to appear. I believe the answer is the below or real similar

```
$A1 = new StdClass();                       
$A1->QuestionID = new StdClass();           
$A1->QuestionID->QuestionID ='Q_CAM_ID';    
$A1->QuestionID->DataType ='string';        
$A1->Value =6838;
```

But what I keep getting is this error
Catchable fatal error Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string when the soap call is done. If anyone has a clue I would be most appreciative

Answer (score 0):

The simliest way to do it is to use a WSDL to php generator as you'll only deal with PHP object that matches the requires types. Moreover, if you a good WSDL to php generator, you'll have PHP classes that are named as the elements.
You could use https://www.wsdltophp.com or https://github.com/mikaelcom/WsdlToPhp.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something but if you need that XML why not just make it as a String, and then convert it to what you are trying to do? If you are not using a WSDL or SimpleXML, I would just do the following.

```
$xml = 
'
<ws:Answer QuestionID="Q_CAM_ID" ws:Datatype="string">
    <ws:Value>6838</ws:Value>
</ws:Answer>
';
```